# c# check if property exists before using it

Tags: c#

```
IndicationBase indication = new IndicationBase(Chatham.Web.UI.Extranet.SessionManager.PhysicalUser);
// check for permissions
LightDataObjectList<TransactionPermission> perms = indication.Model.Trx.TransactionPermissionCollection;
```

So sometimes the `indication` will have a `Model.Trx.TransationPermissionCollection`, and a lot of times it won't. How do I check to see if it does before trying to access it so I don't get an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably you're getting a `NullReferenceException`? Unfortunately there's no nice short cut for this. You have to do something like:

```
if (indication.Model != null &&
    indication.Model.Trx != null)
{
    var perms = indication.Model.Trx.TransactionPermissionCollection;
    // Use perms (which may itself be null)
}
```

Note that the property itself always exists here - static typing and the compiler ensure this - it's just a case of checking whether you've got non-null references everywhere in the property chain.

Of course, if any of the properties are non-nullable types, you don't need to check *those* for nullity :)

Comment: There are ways of using `dynamic` and/or expression trees to work around this issue ... but the're inelegant and overly complicated for the few cases where this is typically needed.

Comment: @LBushkin: Yes, I thought I'd try to avoid getting into that :)